# Syntax to iterate over types for delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

Consider adding multiple health checks via `IHealthChecksBuilder`.

What's the correct syntax to loop through and use classes of the same type?

The following results in

> c is a type but is used like a variable.

How would I define the class for the delegate?

```cs
var checks = new List<Tuple<Type, string, HealthStatus, string[]>>()
{
    new Tuple<Type, string, HealthStatus, string[]>(typeof(CustomHealthCheckService), "some_health_check", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new[] {"tag"}),
    new Tuple<Type, string, HealthStatus, string[]>(typeof(OtherCustomHealthCheckService), "some_other_health_check", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new[] {"other_tag"})
};

IHealthChecksBuilder builder = services.AddHealthChecks();

foreach (var c in checks)
{
    builder.AddCheck<c.Item1>(c.Item2, c.Item3, c.Item4);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `List<Action<IHealthChecksBuilder>>` and populate it with stuff like `builder => builder.AddCheck<CustomHealthCheckService>("some_health_check", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new[] {"tag"})`, then it would just be `foreach(var c in checks) c(builder);`

Comment: Builder should have non-generic version accepting Type. If it doesn't then you are out of luck (can use reflection still but better not). Or use suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to original, the undoubtly cleaner solution properly formatted is:

```
// passed by the user
List<Action<IHealthChecksBuilder>>? checks = new List<Action<IHealthChecksBuilder>>
{
    builder => builder
        .AddCheck<CustomHealthCheckService>("some_health_check", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new[] {"tag1"})
        .AddCheck<OtherCustomHealthCheckService>("some_other_health_check", HealthStatus.Unhealthy, new[] {"tag2"})
};

IHealthChecksBuilder builder = services.AddHealthChecks();

foreach (var c in checks)
{
    c(builder);
}
```